# How to deploy a Pytorch model in IBM Watson Machine learning using Python Client

Tags: api, deployment, pytorch, ibm-watson

I am not able to find any good reference for Deployment of a PyTorch Model in IBM Watson .
I have created Bert Model from Hugging face transformers library and implemented using Pytorch . Now i need to deploy the PyTorch model in IBM watson for real time prediction .

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any good reference of Deployment Steps to follow .

Comment: You can find more information about model deployment at this link https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/DO/WML_Deployment/DeployIntro.html

Comment: Thanks , But i need the steps specific for a pytorch model , I have deployed a scikit learn model and also keras model .But for pytorch model i am not able to find proper steps

Answer (score 0):

have you had a look at :
https://github.com/IBM/pytorch-on-watson-studio ?
This code pattern takes you through the steps to create a model (simple handwritten digit recognizer) in Watson Studio with PyTorch.

Log into IBM Watson Studio
Run the Jupyter notebook in Watson Studio
Use PyTorch to download and process the data
Use Watson Machine Learning to train and deploy the model